# C program for reading doc, docx, pdf

Tags: c, pdf, docx, doc

I want to write a program in C(only c not c++ or java) that will read doc, docx, pdf and want to make it available on github to use for all who needs that code. So I started with .doc file I explored that if I open .doc file with simple notepad it will show you all text but just with some extra content which you can easily trim. So I did write a simple c program to read .doc wile in both 'r' and 'rb' mode but  both time it gives me only 5-9 character in the file and those also not readable. I don't know why it's happening. Any comment or disccussion will be very helpful for me.

**Here is the link for github [Source code](https://github.com/varun-naharia/doc-docx-pdf-Reader-In-C). Please help me to complete all three format.**

Comment: All those formats use different encodings, you will have to look them up. Its not as simple as reading the file with `fopen` and printing it unfortunately.

Comment: I already know that and also studied about them as I told my First problem is reading .doc. My question here is why I am able to read text from .doc while I am opening it notepad or any other text editor but not in C program ?

Comment: It's very bad form to change your question to this extent. This way you're basically a) not giving credit to whomever finds the problem you had in your code and b) you render all of the answers completely useless and incomprehensible for later readers (because you've moved on to a _new_ question by your edits. Please ask new questions in a new question, not by changing your existing one!

Comment: I am not changing the question . The question is how to read doc fox and PDF in c

Comment: Your original question was why your fragment of code didn't read the file properly but stopped. Which I answered. After which you changed the code into something completely different. If you're now stating that your question is the total of how to read these three formats, I'll flag it for overly broad, which it is.

Comment: I know that you gave some useful reply to post but it didn't completely solved the problem I want to finish all three format here don't want ask same question again again and taking risk of mark the thread as duplicate, I am close enough to solve the first problem please cooperate with me

Comment: Your - again edited - question still states "So I did write a simple c program to read .doc wile in both 'r' and 'rb' mode but both time it gives me only 5-9 character in the file and those also not readable". That question is answered. Helping you to fix a complete word, docx and PDF parser in C is way too broad a question for StackOverflow - I've marked your question as too broad to answer. The right thing to do is to implement your code and come back with specific, narrower questions. The rules on this site are to keep things manageable and interesting - please follow them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question, the reason your little application stops reading is because it mistakenly thinks there is an `EOF` character in your file.

Look at your code:

```
char ch;
int nol=0, not=0, nob=0, noc=0;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("file.doc","rb");
while(1)
{
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    if(ch==EOF)
    {
        break;
    }
```

You store the result of `fgetc(fp)` in a variable of type char, which is a single-byte variable. However, the result of fgetc is very purposefully "`int`", not "`char`".

`fgetc` always returns a positive result in the range 0 to 255, except for when you reach the end of the file in which case it returns `EOF`, which is often implemented as a -1 value.

If you read a byte of value 255 and store it in an int, everything is OK, it's stored as the value 255 and your loop can continue. If you store the result in a char, it's going to be interpreted equal to EOF. And your loop stops.

Comment: And that is the proof that neither .doc nor .docx nor .pdf files are anything *near* to "plain text" (with some "extras" that are easy to trim).

Comment: no  I am close to read the .doc file by just trimming extra content

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `.doc` file type as a `txt` file but with extra non-printable characters before, in the middle, and after your content. These non-printable characters are used for defining special formatting, metadata and other infos.

With this said, all `.doc` files follow a certain structure.

If you open two different `.doc` files in a hex editor, you will notice that the text content of both files start at an offset of `0xA00` (2560 bytes) from the beginning of the file. This means that  when you open your file initially, you can ignore the first 2560 bytes of the file (Take a look at the `fseek()` function).

From this point on, you can read the contents of your file until you reach `'\0'`.

I have not seen the implementation of a `.pdf` or a `.docx` file, but you can take open up both files with a hex editor and figure out what pattern you can use the isolate the important contents of the files.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT** : You can always find documentation on the different file formats that you want to manipulate. Here are the specifications of the PDF file type :

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html
http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Comment: Like the way you describe it will replay you as soon as i check that

Comment: *you can take open up both files with a hex editor and figure out* - why not instead reading the specification?

Comment: I tried to fseek first to the offset you said 0xA00 and then tried to read again but the result is same, maybe it should be read as stream i don't know.

Comment: @mkl I have thought about it. I have done some research but couldn't find the correct keywords to get a complete documentation on the filetype. If you have that information, feel free to comment the links so I can edit my answer.

Comment: @VarunNaharia Can you edit your answer with the new changes + show an example of the output that you get please?

Comment: @Cubia for PDF look at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html , especially http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect to get anywhere with this idea.  .doc is a huge binary file format that is inhumanly complicated to parse.  With that said, Cubia mentioned the offset where the text section of the document starts.  I'm not familiar with the details of the format, but if the raw text is contained in one location, use `fseek` to get at it and stop when you reach the end.  This won't be the case for the other formats because they are very different.

.docx and .pdf should be easier to parse because they are more modern formats.  If you want to read anything from a docx you need to read from a zip file with a ton of xml in it and use a parser to figure out which text you want.

.pdf should be the easiest of the three because you might be able to find a library out there that can almost do what you want.

As for why you are getting strange output from your program, remember that .doc is a binary format and the vast majority of the data is garbage from your perspective.  Dumping it to the terminal will yield readable text but also a bunch of control characters that should screw with your terminal.

As a last note - don't try to read docx files directly using `fread` - they are compressed so you likely won't recover the text unaltered.  Take a look at libarchive.  Also - expect to have to read the document specifications.  docx seems to be a microsoft extension to the openoffice format.  See [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) and some PDF specification documents (there are multiple versions).

Comment: thanks for the reply, first I will tell you that I already working on these three format in php and its forking fine but there is no library or program to do the same in c so I just want to make one by converting php function to C, i know all the structure and encoding decoding that is used to make these file. I think docx and pdf much easier but i just started with doc so I have to do it first, docx contains a xml file that I have to read and pdf uses on some encoding that I have to deocde

Comment: "PDF is easier to parse"? That is a pretty bold statement.

Comment: If you think PDF is easier you parse, you haven't read the full specification or have not understood its complexity.

Comment: PDF may not be easy to parse but there are a lot of libraries and applications that you can dissect to make it easier.  Example: https://pdfbox.apache.org/